# What is the state of the art in models of how the human brain performs goal-directed decision making? Can these models' principles be applied to AI?

Tags: models, decision-theory, cognitive-science, brain

What is the state of the art in models of how the human brain performs goal-directed decision making? Can these models’ principles and insights be applied to the field of Artificial Intelligence, e.g. to develop more robust and general AI algorithms?